# Triangle question

Tags: geometry, triangles

I am not able to solve this question from chapter "Similar & Congruent Triangles" in my book.

Can some one help to calculate **AC**?

[image: HERE].

Comment: WAit! According to your question BD + DC = DC + ED = CE = BC. But triangle BDE would then be a straight line, if you remember the triangle inequality!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle CEB \sim \triangle BDE$.

Comment: hey thanks it worked ! i half thought of this but was fooled by the not-to-scale diagram!!!

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCTvV.png)  using triangle similarity 
here the triangle 1 is similar to the triangle 2, also the triangle 2 is similar to the triangle 3

Comment: The text does not say that $BD$ bisects $\widehat{ABC}$, I think.

Comment: and that's not required either :)